# jQuery Progress Bar Not Showing Progress

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I found this Jquery progress bar function and I want to simply use it to show the progress bar while my web page is loading.Actually I included the code and images.The progress bar is showing the percentage but not showing any progress[image: progress image]

please help me.I have also added image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RUBSx/1/

Comment: I followed this fiddle

Comment: $("#progress_bar").progressBar(progress,{barImage:'inc/img/unselected.jpg'} );

Comment: not showing any specific progress just the image i have used covers entire box area

Answer (score 0):

Create a div of, say 150px in width and 15px in height. Then within that div create another with a height of 15px but initially a width of 0.

```
<div style="height:15px; width:150px; background-color:white; ">
    <div style="height:15px;width:0; background-color:blue; "></div>
</div>
```

Then, create a timer that updates every 200ms or so and have the width of the inner div update according to the progress made. Its width becomes (% complete) * 150px.

Comment: I think instead of 0px you should use 0elephants or 0obamas.  It means exactly the same thing.  (In other words, just use 0. Adding a unit to 0 is meaningless!)

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry, I was rushing @DerekHenderson. You know when you've typed 3 'px's already you get into the habit.

Comment: actually plugin itself handles the background and fore ground .My problem is that image not filling completely not as per the percentage value.Is it browser compatibility issue .Iam using IE9

Comment: @user2280657, understandable.  ;)  It's just one of my pet peeves.

Comment: No there is no compatibility issues sorry

Comment: @MadhavanNR, how can we possibly know?  You haven't shared your code!  (And that's probably why your question is getting downvoted.)

Comment: plz temme a suitable solution  @DerekHenderson

Comment: function SetProgress() {

                var statuscount = $("*[id$=hdnchkstatus]").val();
                var statustotal = $("*[id$=hdnchktotal]").val();
                progress = 0,
                 progress = statuscount / statustotal * 100;
                $("#progress_bar").progressBar(progress, { barImage:'inc/img/right.gif' });}

Comment: .aspx code 
                                                
      <span id="progress_bar"></span>

Comment: @MadhavanNR, at the bottom of your question there is a link that says 'edit'.  Click on it and add your code, formatted, to your question.  Then delete the code from these comments where it doesn't belong.